# Setting instance variables on different objects of the same class

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a class called `Person` and person has an attribute called `partner`. When I call `partner=` on one of the `Person` objects, I want to set the `@partner` instance variable of both objects. Here's an example with invalid syntax:

```
class Person

  attr_reader :partner

  def partner=(person)

    # reset the old partner instance variable if it exists
    partner.@partner = nil if partner

    # set the partner attributes
    @partner = person
    person.@partner = self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just discovered `instance_variable_set`.

```
class Person

  attr_reader :partner

  def partner=(person)

    # reset the old partner instance variable if it exists
    partner.instance_variable_set(:@partner, nil) if partner

    # set the partner attributes
    @partner = person
    person.instance_variable_set(:@partner, self)
  end
end
```

Comment: You can definitely access instances variable getters and setters that way, especially if you want the setter to be privately accessible for instance.  In your case, there is probably a better way to achieve what you want.  I think I need a little bit more clarity on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `attr_reader` to an `attr_accessor` and add a helper method:

```
class Person

  attr_accessor :partner

  def link_partners(person)
    @partner = person
    person.partner = self
  end
end
```

Update for visibility.  Based on suggestion from Frederick below.  This is a little more verbose, but will prevent partner from being set directly:

```
class Person
  protected
  attr_writer :partner

  public
  attr_reader :partner

  def link_partners(person)
    @partner = person
    person.partner = self
  end
end
```

Both implementations works like this:

```
p1, p2 = Person.new, Person.new
p1.link_partners(p2) 
# p2.link_partners(p1)
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how that solves my problem. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I was elaborating, but didn't get there before you found the setter.

Comment: The main problem with my solution is that anyone could call person.partner directly and that would only set the person's partner.

Comment: You could make the setter protected.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a protected helper method which gets called by your `partner=` method to do the actual work.  Since it can't be called by "outsiders", all of your check and balances can be maintained in your implementation of `partner=`:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :partner

  def partner=(person)
    @partner.set_partner(nil) if @partner
    set_partner(person)
    person.set_partner(self) if person
  end

  def set_partner(person)
    @partner = person
  end

  protected :set_partner
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could do this as follows:

```
def partner=(person)
  @partner = person
  person.instance_variable_set(:@partner, self)
end
```

However, I would consider this to be magic. (That's not a good thing.) Instead, make the `attr_reader` into an `attr_accessor` and write a different method to set two `person`s' `partner`s to each other.

Comment: I guess I don't feel like it's magic, since it's the behavior I would expect. Documentation would definitely help :)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue with recursive set and looks better than your solution:

```
class Partner
  attr_reader :partner
  def set_partner(person, recursive = true)
    # reset previous partner
    @partner.set_partner(nil, false) if recursive && @partner

    # set new partner
    @partner = person
    @partner.set_partner(self, false) if recursive
  end
  alias_method :partner=, :set_partner
end
```